# Invalid use of Hooks when using onPress to call a function

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I ran into this issue of Invalid hook call. The AltIconButton is a component that I place in the export default function with redirect={GoogleLogin}
Here is my login.js snippet:

```js
const AltIconButton = (props) => {
  console.log(props.name);
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0.5} onPress={props.redirect}>
      <MaterialCommunityIcons
        style={{
          marginHorizontal: 15,
        }}
        name={props.name}
        size={48}
        color="white"
      />
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};
```

Then this is my google_login:

```js
function GoogleLogin() {
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  const [request, response, promptAsync] = Google.useIdTokenAuthRequest({
    expoClientId: Constants.manifest.extra.google.WEB_CLIENT_ID,
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    if (response?.type === "success") {
      const { id_token } = response.params;
      const credential = Firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(id_token);
      Firebase.auth()
        .signInWithCredential(credential)
        .then(() => {
          navigation.replace("Home");
        });
    }
  }, [response]);

  return;
}
```

**EDIT:**
This is another snippet of where I implement my AltIconButton Component

```js
  <View style={styles.bottomBody}>
    <AltIconButton name="facebook" redirect={FBLogin}></AltIconButton>
    <AltIconButton name="google"redirect={GoogleLogin}></AltIconButton>
  </View>
```

Comment: How your are using the AltIconButton component? For ex. share the code where you placed <AltIconButton ..>

Comment: Edited the post, added the snippet of the AltIconButton.

Comment: Okay, your `GoogleLogin` function is a simple JS function(not a React component). You cannot use hooks for ex. `useNavigation` and `useEffect` inside a JavaScript function.https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-from-react-functions

Comment: So I assume I should change the GoogleLogin to a component comprises of the things that I want?

Comment: Yes, but I am not sure what you want to achieve and what's your auth flow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By changing the JS function into its own component solve the problem.

For example:

```js
function GoogleLogin() {
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  const [request, response, promptAsync] = Google.useIdTokenAuthRequest({
    expoClientId: Constants.manifest.extra.google.WEB_CLIENT_ID,
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    if (response?.type === "success") {
      const { id_token } = response.params;
      const credential = Firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(id_token);
      Firebase.auth()
        .signInWithCredential(credential)
        .then(() => {
          navigation.replace("Home");
        });
    }
  }, [response]);

  return (
    <TouchableOpacity
      disabled={!request}
      activeOpacity={0.5}
      onPress={() => promptAsync()}
    />
  );
}
```